# How to check if user has checked captcha checkbox javascript

Tags: recaptcha

I have this below form. How i can check if the user has clicked the captcha checkbox and display an error if user has not checked the captcha checkbox.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You can use the data-callback to find when it has been completed. As for an error when it is not filled the only way is to prevent the submit of your form and maybe show a tooltip or error message and then use the callback to then allow your form to submit. [See for more info](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display#render_param)